# Create Object from String and reverse

Tags: javascript

I'm currently working on a personal highscore feature for a Minesweeper implementation I'm doing in Vue.js 2.x ([working demo](http://connexo.de/defuse)).

As of now, I'm planning to create a single localStorage item for these personal records

```
localStorage.setItem('defuse-records', 'easy:121,medium:455,hard:781,insane:')
```

The numbers represent the seconds that it took the person to solve the different difficulty presets. In the example the person hasn't solved `insane` yet.

I would like to create an object from this string that looks like this:

```
{ easy: 121, medium: 455, hard: 781, insane: null }
```

This is what I've done so far:

```
getLocalRecords() {
  let localRecords = localStorage.getItem('defuse-records')
  if(!localRecords) {
    return { easy: null, medium: null, hard: null, insane: null }
  }  
  let strArray = localRecords.split(',')
  let recordsObj = strArray.map(function (str) {
    let rObj = {}
    rObj[str.split(':')[0]] = str.split(':')[1] || null
    return rObj
  })

  return recordsObj
}
```

However, due to the nature of `Array.prototype.map`, that returns an `Array` and not an `Object`:

```
[{ easy: 121}, { medium: 455 }, { hard: 781 }, { insane: null }]
```

Now I can of course iterate over this Array and create the object I want, but this feels complicated and I was hoping for someone to have a more elegant way of converting in both directions.

Maybe someone sees a solution immediately?

2nd question: Would there be a better suited, easier to use way to use a single storage item to store the personal records for all four difficulty levels?

Comment: Why not simply `JSON.parse` ?

Comment: don't use map, use reduce.

Comment: I don't understand why this question is getting downvoted. Maybe those who did can elaborate on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to slightly modify your original item in order to use JSON parse which would be the simplest way I think

```
localStorage.setItem('defuse-records', '{"easy":121,"medium":455,"hard":781,"insane":null}');
```

Then you can do:

```
getLocalRecords(){
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('defuse-records') || '{"easy":null,"medium":null,"hard":null,"insane":null}');
    // {easy: 121, medium: 455, hard: 781, insane: null}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just use `reduce` for this task:

```
'easy:121,medium:455,hard:781,insane:'
    .split(",")
    .reduce((obj, item)=>{ 
        let [key, value] = item.split(':'); 
        obj[key] = +value || null; 
        return obj;
    }, {})
//evaluates to {easy: 121, medium: 455, hard: 781, insane: null}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 getLocalRecords(){
    const localRecords = localStorage.getItem('defuse-records').split(",");
    const result = {};
    for(const pair of localRecords){
       const [key, val] = pair.split(":");
       result[key] = +val;
    }
    return result;
 }
```

Or functional:

```
  getLocalRecords(){
    return Object.assign({}, ...localStorage.getItem('defuse-records').split(",").map(pair => (([key, val]) => ({[key]: val}))(pair.split(":"))));
 }
```

Or using reduce:

```
 getLocalRecords(){
   return localStorage.getItem('defuse-records')
         .split(",")
         .map(pair => pair.split(":"))
         .reduce((result, [key, val]) => {
             result[key] = val;
             return result;
         }, {});
 }
```

However i would rather simply use `JSON.stringify` & `parse`:

```
 function store(settings){
   localStorage.setItem('defuse-records', settings);
 }

 function load(){
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('defuse-records'));
 }
```

Comment: Not sure if `+val` returns `null` for empty string.

Comment: In your comment, you suggested using JSON.parse - which is the obvious approach I overlooked. With your second suggestion, can't I just go `return { ...localStorage.getItem('defuse-records'). /*etc */ }` ?

Comment: `const s = ""; +s === null // false`

Comment: `+""` evaluates to `0`

Comment: So it would be `+val || null`

Comment: Again, why are you suggesting using `Object.assign({}, ...spread)` instead of just `{ ...spread }`?

Comment: @connexo well, then `easy:0` would fail. Maybe `val.length? +val: null`

Comment: `0` should actually be impossible to score.

Comment: @connexo cause in that example the spreaded thing is an array, so `{...spread}` would return `{0:what, 1:ever}`

Comment: If that is an array, how can you use it as an argument for `Object.assign()`? I thought that only takes objects as arguments.

Comment: @connexo its spread into object assigns arguments, e.g. `Object.assign({}, what, ever)` and the arrays elements are objects. However just use either the last or the first solution, the others are just a beautifully ugly way